# i cant call the method in swift file

Tags: objective-c, swift

I want to call a method from objective c to swift file. but its showing me value of `DCSideMenuViewController` has no member `viewControllerFromMenuItem`

I have import objective c file in bridging-header.h but working

1. This is a swift file

   ```
   let obj:DCSideMenuViewController = DCSideMenuViewController()
    DCSideMenuViewController().viewControllerFromMenuItem
   ```

2.This is objective C file

```
- (DCBaseViewController*)viewControllerFromMenuItem: (DCMenuSection)menuItemandControllerId:(NSString*)controllerId {
    NSString* storyboardName = [selfstoryboardNameForMenuItem:menuItem];
    UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
    if ([controllerId isEqualToString:@"DCFloorPlanController"]) {
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SMain" bundle:nil];
    }
```

Value of type `DCSideMenuViewController` has no member `viewControllerFromMenuItem`

Comment: The method has 2 parameters which you didn't put in your Swift code. And there is not autcompletion?

Comment: so how to do can you please help me

Comment: In your swift file -> `let obj = DCSideMenuViewController()
 obj.viewControllerFromMenuItem` try this

Comment: @EmreCiftci i have tried

Comment: Have you checked if the Obj-C method that you have shared is declared in the .h file too? If not, it won't be visible

Comment: Your function in the obj-c code has a - before the function. You are trying to call it as a class function so will need a + instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method should be translated into the following Swift method:

```
func fromMenuItem(_ menuItem: DCMenuSection, andControllerId controllerId: String) -> DCBaseViewController
```

You can always look into generated Swift interface to find available methods.

In the following proposal you can find how Objective C API is translated into Swift: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0005-objective-c-name-translation.md

Your case can be found at Pruning Steps -> 4. Prune a match for the enclosing type from the base name of a method so long as the match starts after a verb.